# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoReportTask$JacocoReportWorkerAction

Tags: android, jacoco

I want to generate code coverage for my project so I have added ,

```
debug {
      
        testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

When i run command `gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` I get the following error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoReportTask$JacocoReportWorkerAction
  
  >Unable to generate Jacoco report
```

Using same gradle version and kotlin version worked in sample project ,
Its giving error in my main project .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of research I found out it was problem with jacoco , Thanks to this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44757) and its commentors in youtrack which pointed me out in right direction . To fix the issue upgrade the jacoco to version 0.8.7

in app level `build.gradle` file add these following lines

```
plugins{
    ...
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacoco {
   toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

android {
   ...
}

dependencies{
  ...
}

configurations.all{
resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { details ->
        if ('org.jacoco' == details.requested.group) {
            details.useVersion "0.8.7"
        }
    }
   }
}
```

I am not sure why it worked in sample app

Answer (score 2):

If in-case, if you use `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    ...
    jacoco
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if (requested.group == "org.jacoco") {
                useVersion("0.8.7")
            }
        }
    }
}
```