# Gradle task :app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport fails, why?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, jacoco, android-jacoco

When I run `gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` it fails with:

> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
> Starting 1 tests on Tablet_Sv2(AVD) - 12

> Test results saved as file:/../app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/flavors/app/Tablet_Sv2(AVD)%20-%2012/test-result.pb. Inspect these results in Android Studio by selecting Run > Import Tests From File from the menu bar and importing test-
> result.pb.

> Task :app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoReportTask$JacocoReportWorkerAction
> Unable to generate Jacoco report

Why?

EDIT:
[According to this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066093/5102206) the app level build.gradle would require

```
configurations.all{
resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { details ->
        if ('org.jacoco' == details.requested.group) {
            details.useVersion "0.8.7"
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why should it not fail, I mean, new Android Studio takes 3 GB RAM for no reason (if left open for a while), and many Android-Gradle-Plugin versions are unstable as well, hence one needs to find what works and stick with it until Google adds next stable version. Try: "Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 2" with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'`

Comment: See also: [**Why is the 'connectedDebugAndroidTest' Gradle task hanging indefinitely?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77065504/8740349)