# Why is the 'connectedDebugAndroidTest' Gradle task hanging indefinitely in my Android application projects?

Tags: android-studio, android-testing

I have a couple of longstanding Android application projects which I returned to this week after a couple of months away.

When I run the `connectedAndroidTest` (specifically: `connectedDebugAndroidTest`) Gradle task in these projects, the Gradle task just hangs indefinitely and no tests run on the Android device. This is demonstrated in the following screenshot:

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

I have tested and observed this behaviour in the following environments thus far:

| Android Studio version | macOS version |
| --- | --- |
| Giraffe (2022.3.1 Patch 2) | Ventura 13.6 |
| Electric Eel (2022.1.1 Patch 2) | Ventura 13.1 |
| Dolphin (2021.3.1 Patch 1) | Ventura 13.1 |

Is anybody else experiencing this? Have you managed to find the root cause of the problem?

#### Notes

1. This problem persists for me despite restarting Android Studio and despite restarting my machine.
2. This problem exists for me in different Android projects and on different macOS machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I peeled away at the build tools and libraries in my application projects and managed to find the root cause of the problem.

The problem was the following dependency declaration:

```
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5'
```

I created a minimal Android application project [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-test-experiments/tree/master/app2) which demonstrates the problem. Run the `connectedDebugAndroidTest` Gradle task in this project and you will observe that the Gradle task hangs indefinitely. Remove the `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` dependency from the [build.gradle](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-test-experiments/blob/master/app2/build.gradle) file in this project and re-run the `connectedDebugAndroidTest` Gradle task. This time you will observe that the Gradle task runs to completion swiftly.

If your project actually requires the [androidx.fragment:fragment-testing](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.fragment:fragment-testing) library, the fix is to change your `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` dependency declaration to the following:

```
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing-manifest:1.6.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.6.0'
```

For a detailed discussion about the `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` dependency declaration, see [Issue #128612536](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128612536) in [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The newer Android Studio versions (like 2022.3.1) had similar issue, while trying to debug my instrumented-tests.

> Most (if not all) "tests" are code as well, and sometime need to be debugged, like to know why test fails.

**But** it had nothing to do with "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing".

The fix was to install "Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 2" instead, which works best with Android-Gradle-Plugin version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
```

For why `7.1.3`, see https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/940

> **Note** that I always set "Debug type" of my "Android Instrumented Tests" run configuration from "Detect automatically" to "Java only", because the native thing is broken since years
> (but same issue, can not debug, unless I downgrade).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, all my Espresso tests worked previously, but mysteriously started hanging on the Gradle task.
After some troubleshooting, I discovered (from Activity Monitor/Task Manager) that there was an ADB process that was hung.

I deleted the rogue ADB process, and just for good measure, rebooted my Mac.

My Espresso tests started working after that.

Comment: Phileo99, I added a couple of notes to my question to clarify that the problem which I was experiencing was not a temperamental one but a permanent one.